# Cuda Create 3d texture and cudaArray(3d) from device memory

Tags: c++, c, arrays, cuda, textures

im trying to create a texture 3d from a part of a device array.

To do this, these are my steps:

1. malloc Device Array
2. Write Device Array
3. Create CudaArray (3D)
4. Bind Texture to CudaArray

The way im doing it it creates no compiler errors, but when i run cuda-memcheck it's failing when im trying to fetch data from the Texture.

> Invalid **global** read of size 8 .. Address 0x10dfaf3a0 is out of bounds

Thats why i'm guessing i declared the texture Array wrong.
here is how i access the texture:

> tex3D(NoiseTextures[i],x,y,z)

The way im doing the steps mentioned above:

1.Malloc Device Array

```
cudaMalloc((void **)&d_Noise, sqrSizeNoise*nNoise*sizeof(float));
```

2.Write Device Array

```
curandCreateGenerator(&gen,CURAND_RNG_PSEUDO_DEFAULT);
curandSetPseudoRandomGeneratorSeed(gen,Seed);
curandGenerateUniform(gen, d_Noise, sqrSizeNoise*nNoise);
curandDestroyGenerator(gen);
```

3+4.Creating the Cuda Array and binding it to the texture (Im guessing the mistake is here)

```
cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<float>();//cudaCreateChannelDesc(32, 0, 0, 0, cudaChannelFormatKindFloat);
cudaArray *d_cuArr;
cudaMalloc3DArray(&d_cuArr, &channelDesc, make_cudaExtent(SizeNoise,SizeNoise,SizeNoise), 0);
cudaMemcpy3DParms copyParams = {0};

//Loop for every separated Noise Texture (nNoise = 4)
for(int i = 0; i < nNoise; i++){

    //initialize the textures
    NoiseTextures[i] = texture<float, 3, cudaReadModeElementType>(1,cudaFilterModeLinear,cudaAddressModeWrap,channelDesc);

    //Array creation
    //+(sqrSizeNoise*i) is to separate the created Noise Array into smaller parts with the size of SizeNoise^3
    copyParams.srcPtr   = make_cudaPitchedPtr(d_Noise+(sqrSizeNoise*i), SizeNoise*sizeof(float), SizeNoise, SizeNoise);
    copyParams.dstArray = d_cuArr;
    copyParams.extent   = make_cudaExtent(SizeNoise,SizeNoise,SizeNoise);
    copyParams.kind     = cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy3D(&copyParams));
    //Array creation End

    //new Bind
    // set texture parameters
    NoiseTextures[i].normalized = true;                      // access with normalized texture coordinates
    NoiseTextures[i].filterMode = cudaFilterModeLinear;      // linear interpolation
    NoiseTextures[i].addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeWrap;   // wrap texture coordinates
    NoiseTextures[i].addressMode[1] = cudaAddressModeWrap;
    NoiseTextures[i].addressMode[2] = cudaAddressModeWrap;

    // bind array to 3D texture
    checkCudaErrors(cudaBindTextureToArray(NoiseTextures[i], d_cuArr, channelDesc));
    //end Bind
}
cudaFreeArray(d_cuArr);
```

I've Pasted this code snippet to Pastebin so its easier to look at with colors etc.
http://pastebin.com/SM3dYd38

I hope I clearly described my problem. If not pls comment!

Can you help me with this?
Thanks for reading,

Cery

Edit:
Here is a complete code so you can try it on your own machine:

```
#include <helper_cuda.h>  
#include <helper_functions.h>
#include <helper_cuda_gl.h>
#include <texture_types.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <curand.h>

static texture<float, 3, cudaReadModeElementType> NoiseTextures[4];//texture Array
float *d_NoiseTest;//Device Array with random floats
int SizeNoiseTest = 32;
int sqrSizeNoiseTest = 32768;

void CreateTexture();

__global__ void AccesTexture(texture<float, 3, cudaReadModeElementType>* NoiseTextures)
{
        int test = tex3D(NoiseTextures[0],threadIdx.x,threadIdx.y,threadIdx.z);//by using this the error occurs
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        CreateTexture();
}
void CreateTexture()
{
        //curand Random Generator (needs compiler link -lcurand)
        curandGenerator_t gen;
        cudaMalloc((void **)&d_NoiseTest, sqrSizeNoiseTest*4*sizeof(float));//Allocation of device Array
        curandCreateGenerator(&gen,CURAND_RNG_PSEUDO_DEFAULT);
        curandSetPseudoRandomGeneratorSeed(gen,1234ULL);
        curandGenerateUniform(gen, d_NoiseTest, sqrSizeNoiseTest*4);//writing data to d_NoiseTest
        curandDestroyGenerator(gen);

        //cudaArray Descriptor
        cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<float>();
        //cuda Array
        cudaArray *d_cuArr;
        cudaMalloc3DArray(&d_cuArr, &channelDesc, make_cudaExtent(SizeNoiseTest*sizeof(float),SizeNoiseTest,SizeNoiseTest), 0);
        cudaMemcpy3DParms copyParams = {0};

        //Loop for every separated Noise Texture (4 = 4)
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){

                //initialize the textures
                NoiseTextures[i] = texture<float, 3, cudaReadModeElementType>(1,cudaFilterModeLinear,cudaAddressModeWrap,channelDesc);

                //Array creation
                //+(sqrSizeNoise*i) is to separate the created Noise Array into smaller parts with the size of SizeNoise^3
                copyParams.srcPtr   = make_cudaPitchedPtr(d_NoiseTest+(sqrSizeNoiseTest*i), SizeNoiseTest*sizeof(float), SizeNoiseTest, SizeNoiseTest);
                copyParams.dstArray = d_cuArr;
                copyParams.extent   = make_cudaExtent(SizeNoiseTest*sizeof(float),SizeNoiseTest,SizeNoiseTest);
                copyParams.kind     = cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice;
                checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy3D(&copyParams));
                //Array creation End

                //new Bind
                // set texture parameters
                NoiseTextures[i].normalized = true;                      // access with normalized texture coordinates
                NoiseTextures[i].filterMode = cudaFilterModeLinear;      // linear interpolation
                NoiseTextures[i].addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeWrap;   // wrap texture coordinates
                NoiseTextures[i].addressMode[1] = cudaAddressModeWrap;
                NoiseTextures[i].addressMode[2] = cudaAddressModeWrap;

                // bind array to 3D texture
                checkCudaErrors(cudaBindTextureToArray(NoiseTextures[i], d_cuArr, channelDesc));
                //end Bind
        }
        cudaFreeArray(d_cuArr);

        AccesTexture<<<1,dim3(4,4,4)>>>(NoiseTextures);
}
```

You need to link -lcurand though. And include CUDA-6.0/samples/common/inc

Im now getting a different error in this code

> code=11(cudaErrorInvalidValue) "cudaMemcpy3D(&copyParams)"

Even though it's the exact same code then my original. - Im starting to get completely confused.
Thank you for your help

Comment: 1. Provide a *short*, complete code, that someone could copy, paste, compile, and run, to see the error.  SO [expects this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 2. Why do you want to use an array of textures? Is it possible to use a single texture with an offset into that texture instead for each sub-texture? Alternatively, have you looked at layered textures? 3. What GPU do you intend to use?  I ask because an array of texture *objects* (cc3.0 and newer) may be workable, but there are issues/limitations.

Comment: make_cudaExtent() has its first parameter as width in bytes, so as far as I can guess it should be `make_cudaExtent(SizeNoise*sizeof(float),SizeNoise,SizeNoise);`

Comment: thank you for coping with my issue! 
Robert Crovella: I have created a short complete code snippet so you can try it. FindError.cu : pastebin.com/viQYFGA7 I also edited the original post.
2. It might be possible to use a big texture and offset the values, but i fought it would be easier to create multiple, because i want to map the textures multiple times periodically. I thought the adressModeWrap would be a good way to do that. 
Layered Textures aren't able to be 3d right?
Im aiming for cc3.0 so texture objects might be possible.
Kamil Czerski: I tried that, but the error still occurs.

Comment: *You should edit your question to include the full code sample, not a link to it.*  When I compile and run that sample, I get a different error: "CUDA error at t505.cu:66 code=18(cudaErrorInvalidTexture) "cudaBindTextureToArray(NoiseTextures[i], d_cuArr, channelDesc)""  This is more or less what I expected.  I don't think you can create an array of textures using the Texture Reference API.  Are you saying you can compile the full code sample you provided, and run it, and you get past the texture creation and are able to launch the kernel and see an invalid global read?

Comment: You might do well to get your 3D texture code working for a *single* ordinary (non-array-of) texture first.  `dim3(32,32,32)` is not a valid threadblock configuration for any current CUDA GPU.  You could not possibly be running that kernel, regardless of any preceding code.  and we don't pass a texture reference as a parameter to a kernel.  It is a static entity. You just use it.  Probably best if you study basic texturing first.

Comment: Yes i did that wrong with the thread size, in my original code i did it right, just forgot while doing this example code. Sorry. I'll try to create a single texture first, then i'll do the multiple texture thing. I guess its a good idea. Thank You!

Comment: if you want to see a "fixed" version of your 3D texturing, working with a single 3D texture, it is [here](http://pastebin.com/BWdbR0bk).

Comment: @KamilCzerski the extent used for the 3D copy parameters is not specified in terms of bytes but rather elements, if a cudaArray is participating in the `cudaMemcpy3D` operation.  Refer to the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1gc1372614eb614f4689fbb82b4692d30a)

Comment: @RobertCrovella You are right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a worked example showing the creation of an array of texture objects, roughly following the path of the code you provided.  You can see, by comparing to the texture reference code I placed [here](http://pastebin.com/BWdbR0bk), that the first set of texture reads from the first texture object (i.e. the first kernel call) are the same numerical values as the set of reads from the texture reference example (you may need to adjust the grid size of the two example codes to match).

Texture object usage requires compute capability 3.0 or higher.

example:

```
$ cat t507.cu
#include <helper_cuda.h>
#include <curand.h>
#define NUM_TEX 4

const int SizeNoiseTest = 32;
const int cubeSizeNoiseTest = SizeNoiseTest*SizeNoiseTest*SizeNoiseTest;
static cudaTextureObject_t texNoise[NUM_TEX];

__global__ void AccesTexture(cudaTextureObject_t my_tex)
{
        float test = tex3D<float>(my_tex,(float)threadIdx.x,(float)threadIdx.y,(float)threadIdx.z);//by using this the error occurs
        printf("thread: %d,%d,%d, value: %f\n", threadIdx.x, threadIdx.y, threadIdx.z, test);
}

void CreateTexture()
{

    float *d_NoiseTest;//Device Array with random floats
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_NoiseTest, cubeSizeNoiseTest*sizeof(float));//Allocation of device Array
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TEX; i++){
        //curand Random Generator (needs compiler link -lcurand)
        curandGenerator_t gen;
        curandCreateGenerator(&gen,CURAND_RNG_PSEUDO_DEFAULT);
        curandSetPseudoRandomGeneratorSeed(gen,1235ULL+i);
        curandGenerateUniform(gen, d_NoiseTest, cubeSizeNoiseTest);//writing data to d_NoiseTest
        curandDestroyGenerator(gen);

        //cudaArray Descriptor
        cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<float>();
        //cuda Array
        cudaArray *d_cuArr;
        checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc3DArray(&d_cuArr, &channelDesc, make_cudaExtent(SizeNoiseTest*sizeof(float),SizeNoiseTest,SizeNoiseTest), 0));
        cudaMemcpy3DParms copyParams = {0};


        //Array creation
        copyParams.srcPtr   = make_cudaPitchedPtr(d_NoiseTest, SizeNoiseTest*sizeof(float), SizeNoiseTest, SizeNoiseTest);
        copyParams.dstArray = d_cuArr;
        copyParams.extent   = make_cudaExtent(SizeNoiseTest,SizeNoiseTest,SizeNoiseTest);
        copyParams.kind     = cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice;
        checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy3D(&copyParams));
        //Array creation End

        cudaResourceDesc    texRes;
        memset(&texRes, 0, sizeof(cudaResourceDesc));
        texRes.resType = cudaResourceTypeArray;
        texRes.res.array.array  = d_cuArr;
        cudaTextureDesc     texDescr;
        memset(&texDescr, 0, sizeof(cudaTextureDesc));
        texDescr.normalizedCoords = false;
        texDescr.filterMode = cudaFilterModeLinear;
        texDescr.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeClamp;   // clamp
        texDescr.addressMode[1] = cudaAddressModeClamp;
        texDescr.addressMode[2] = cudaAddressModeClamp;
        texDescr.readMode = cudaReadModeElementType;
        checkCudaErrors(cudaCreateTextureObject(&texNoise[i], &texRes, &texDescr, NULL));}
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        CreateTexture();
        AccesTexture<<<1,dim3(2,2,2)>>>(texNoise[0]);
        AccesTexture<<<1,dim3(2,2,2)>>>(texNoise[1]);
        AccesTexture<<<1,dim3(2,2,2)>>>(texNoise[2]);
        checkCudaErrors(cudaPeekAtLastError());
        checkCudaErrors(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
        return 0;
}
```

compile with:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_30 -I/shared/apps/cuda/CUDA-v6.0.37/samples/common/inc -lcurand -o t507 t507.cu
```

output:

```
$ cuda-memcheck ./t507
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
thread: 0,0,0, value: 0.310691
thread: 1,0,0, value: 0.627906
thread: 0,1,0, value: 0.638900
thread: 1,1,0, value: 0.665186
thread: 0,0,1, value: 0.167465
thread: 1,0,1, value: 0.565227
thread: 0,1,1, value: 0.397606
thread: 1,1,1, value: 0.503013
thread: 0,0,0, value: 0.809163
thread: 1,0,0, value: 0.795669
thread: 0,1,0, value: 0.808565
thread: 1,1,0, value: 0.847564
thread: 0,0,1, value: 0.853998
thread: 1,0,1, value: 0.688446
thread: 0,1,1, value: 0.733255
thread: 1,1,1, value: 0.649379
thread: 0,0,0, value: 0.040824
thread: 1,0,0, value: 0.087417
thread: 0,1,0, value: 0.301392
thread: 1,1,0, value: 0.298669
thread: 0,0,1, value: 0.161962
thread: 1,0,1, value: 0.316443
thread: 0,1,1, value: 0.452077
thread: 1,1,1, value: 0.477722
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
```

In this case I'm using the same kernel, called multiple times, to read from the individual texture objects.  It should be possible to pass multiple objects to the same kernel, however it is not advisable to have a single *warp* read from multiple textures, if that can be avoided in your code.  The actual issue resides at the quad level, which I'd prefer not to get into.  It's best if you can arrange your code so that a warp is reading from the same texture object, on any given cycle.

Note that for simplicity of presentation, this `CreateTexture()` function overwrites previously allocated device pointers such as  `d_cuArr`, during the processing of the loop.  This isn't illegal or a functional issue, but it raises the possibility of memory leaks.

I assume you can modify the code to handle deallocation of those if this is a concern.  The purpose of this code is to demonstrate the method to get things working.

Answer (score 1):

In cudaMalloc3DArray, it should be something like this make_cudaExtent(SizeNoiseTest,SizeNoiseTest,SizeNoiseTest) not
make_cudaExtent(SizeNoiseTest*sizeof(float),SizeNoiseTest,SizeNoiseTest)