# cuda 2D layered tex size: too large?

Tags: memory, cuda, texture2d

Following if the code to initiate a 3D array in cuda with size being width = 809; hight = 127; and number of layers = 2160;

```
cudaArray *sinor;
    cudaExtent volumeSize = make_cudaExtent(809, 127, 2160);
const cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<float>();
gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc3DArray(&sinor, &channelDesc, volumeSize, cudaArrayLayered));
```

last line returns error "invalid argument" error. Is that because my number of layer is too large? I tried 1940, and it was fine. If I cannot do such a large number of layers, what is the work around here ? Thanks alot.

Comment: The layer limit is 2048 - check `deviceQuery`

Comment: @RobertCrovella: is there a work-around?

Comment: You could have [two texture objects/references](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-pro-tip-kepler-texture-objects-improve-performance-and-flexibility/), and select between the two based on the layer index.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Let me try it out. A pointer of tex, or a vector of tex? That works for CUDA?

Comment: You don't need pointers or vectors of anything.  Do you know how to create a texture object?  Great.  Create 2 of them.   Let's call one texA and the other texB. When it comes time to do the texture fetching, if your preferred layer index is less than 2048, texture from texA.  If your preferred layer index is greater than 2048, texture from texB, but subtract 2048 from your preferred layer index.  This is a simple if-then-else statement with 2 textures.  No pointers or vectors of anything.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks Robert. I was thinking of a series of 2D tex if splitting is an option. So vector is the first thing coming up in my mind.

Comment: You can create an [array of texture objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24981310/cuda-create-3d-texture-and-cudaarray3d-from-device-memory/24990338#24990338).  I haven't tried that with layered textures, but I think it should be possible.  I don't know how to create an array of texture references.  I personally wouldn't try using a **vector** in device code, but you may have other ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the texture layer depth limit on the documentation [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications).  As you inferred, the depth limit for layered textures and surfaces is 2048.

As was suggested in comments, your only real workaround here is to split your data over  multiple texture objects and select between the objects based on index within the virtual combined textures.