# Array of cudaArray for multi-GPU texture code

Tags: cuda

I have some code that I am trying to get to work for a general multi-GPU case, for `n` amount of equal devices, where `n` is unknown at compile time.

For this code, I need to bind to texture memory some array, and I need exactly the same data to be bound to the different GPUs.

My single GPU memory code for 3D texture binding looks like:

```
cudaArray *d_imagedata = 0;
const cudaExtent extent = make_cudaExtent(geo.nVoxelX, geo.nVoxelY, geo.nVoxelZ);
cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<float>();
cudaMalloc3DArray(&d_imagedata, &channelDesc, extent);
cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc3D error 3D tex");

cudaMemcpy3DParms copyParams = { 0 };
copyParams.srcPtr = make_cudaPitchedPtr((void*)img, extent.width*sizeof(float), extent.width, extent.height);
copyParams.dstArray = d_imagedata;
copyParams.extent = extent;
copyParams.kind = cudaMemcpyHostToDevice;
cudaMemcpy3D(&copyParams);

cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy3D fail");

// Configure texture options
tex.normalized = false;
tex.filterMode = cudaFilterModePoint; 
tex.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeBorder;
tex.addressMode[1] = cudaAddressModeBorder;
tex.addressMode[2] = cudaAddressModeBorder;

cudaBindTextureToArray(tex, d_imagedata, channelDesc);
```

Its the standard copy to a `cudaArray` and then binding and setting process, nothing new here.

To transform this code into multi GPU I am aware that I do not need to change the `tex` global texture reference, as CUDA will know that different GPUs have different `tex`, however I do need `n` `cudaArray *d_imagedata` instances, one for each GPU.

How do I make (and allocate) an array of `cudaArray`s?

If it was global memory pointers it would be easier, just a CPU `malloc` on a double pointer and then `cudaMalloc` on each of them would work, but as a `cudaArray` is not a standard type, I haven't figured out how to create a flexible array out of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using texture objects, rather than texture references.

Using [texture objects](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#texture-functions), a trivial modification to the code presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24981310/cuda-create-3d-texture-and-cudaarray3d-from-device-memory/24990338#24990338) seems to work correctly for me:

```
$ cat t341.cu
#include <helper_cuda.h>
#include <curand.h>
#define NUM_TEX 4

const int SizeNoiseTest = 32;
const int cubeSizeNoiseTest = SizeNoiseTest*SizeNoiseTest*SizeNoiseTest;
static cudaTextureObject_t texNoise[NUM_TEX];

__global__ void AccesTexture(cudaTextureObject_t my_tex)
{
        float test = tex3D<float>(my_tex,(float)threadIdx.x,(float)threadIdx.y,(float)threadIdx.z);//by using this the error occurs
        printf("thread: %d,%d,%d, value: %f\n", threadIdx.x, threadIdx.y, threadIdx.z, test);
}

void CreateTexture()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TEX; i++){
        cudaSetDevice(i);
        float *d_NoiseTest;//Device Array with random floats
        cudaMalloc((void **)&d_NoiseTest, cubeSizeNoiseTest*sizeof(float));//Allocation of device Array
        //curand Random Generator (needs compiler link -lcurand)
        curandGenerator_t gen;
        curandCreateGenerator(&gen,CURAND_RNG_PSEUDO_DEFAULT);
        curandSetPseudoRandomGeneratorSeed(gen,1235ULL+i);
        curandGenerateUniform(gen, d_NoiseTest, cubeSizeNoiseTest);//writing data to d_NoiseTest
        curandDestroyGenerator(gen);

        //cudaArray Descriptor
        cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<float>();
        //cuda Array
        cudaArray *d_cuArr;
        checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc3DArray(&d_cuArr, &channelDesc, make_cudaExtent(SizeNoiseTest*sizeof(float),SizeNoiseTest,SizeNoiseTest), 0));
        cudaMemcpy3DParms copyParams = {0};


        //Array creation
        copyParams.srcPtr   = make_cudaPitchedPtr(d_NoiseTest, SizeNoiseTest*sizeof(float), SizeNoiseTest, SizeNoiseTest);
        copyParams.dstArray = d_cuArr;
        copyParams.extent   = make_cudaExtent(SizeNoiseTest,SizeNoiseTest,SizeNoiseTest);
        copyParams.kind     = cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice;
        checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy3D(&copyParams));
        //Array creation End

        cudaResourceDesc    texRes;
        memset(&texRes, 0, sizeof(cudaResourceDesc));
        texRes.resType = cudaResourceTypeArray;
        texRes.res.array.array  = d_cuArr;
        cudaTextureDesc     texDescr;
        memset(&texDescr, 0, sizeof(cudaTextureDesc));
        texDescr.normalizedCoords = false;
        texDescr.filterMode = cudaFilterModeLinear;
        texDescr.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeClamp;   // clamp
        texDescr.addressMode[1] = cudaAddressModeClamp;
        texDescr.addressMode[2] = cudaAddressModeClamp;
        texDescr.readMode = cudaReadModeElementType;
        checkCudaErrors(cudaCreateTextureObject(&texNoise[i], &texRes, &texDescr, NULL));}
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        CreateTexture();
        cudaSetDevice(0);
        AccesTexture<<<1,dim3(2,2,2)>>>(texNoise[0]);
        cudaSetDevice(1);
        AccesTexture<<<1,dim3(2,2,2)>>>(texNoise[1]);
        cudaSetDevice(2);
        AccesTexture<<<1,dim3(2,2,2)>>>(texNoise[2]);
        checkCudaErrors(cudaPeekAtLastError());
        cudaSetDevice(0);
        checkCudaErrors(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
        cudaSetDevice(1);
        checkCudaErrors(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
        cudaSetDevice(2);
        checkCudaErrors(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
        return 0;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_30 -I/usr/local/cuda/samples/common/inc -lcurand -o t341 t341.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t341
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
thread: 0,0,0, value: 0.310691
thread: 1,0,0, value: 0.627906
thread: 0,1,0, value: 0.638900
thread: 1,1,0, value: 0.665186
thread: 0,0,1, value: 0.167465
thread: 1,0,1, value: 0.565227
thread: 0,1,1, value: 0.397606
thread: 1,1,1, value: 0.503013
thread: 0,0,0, value: 0.809163
thread: 1,0,0, value: 0.795669
thread: 0,1,0, value: 0.808565
thread: 1,1,0, value: 0.847564
thread: 0,0,1, value: 0.853998
thread: 1,0,1, value: 0.688446
thread: 0,1,1, value: 0.733255
thread: 1,1,1, value: 0.649379
thread: 0,0,0, value: 0.040824
thread: 1,0,0, value: 0.087417
thread: 0,1,0, value: 0.301392
thread: 1,1,0, value: 0.298669
thread: 0,0,1, value: 0.161962
thread: 1,0,1, value: 0.316443
thread: 0,1,1, value: 0.452077
thread: 1,1,1, value: 0.477722
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Note that for simplicity of presentation, this `CreateTexture()` function overwrites previously allocated device pointers such as `d_NoiseTest` and `d_cuArr`, during the processing of the loop.  This isn't illegal or a functional issue, but it raises the possibility of memory leaks.  (But see below for an example of how to avoid this.)

**EDIT:** Based on a question in the comments, none of this should be compile-time dependent.    Here's a modification of the above code demonstrating this:

```
$ cat t342.cu
#include <helper_cuda.h>
#include <curand.h>

const int SizeNoiseTest = 32;
const int cubeSizeNoiseTest = SizeNoiseTest*SizeNoiseTest*SizeNoiseTest;

__global__ void AccesTexture(cudaTextureObject_t my_tex)
{
        float test = tex3D<float>(my_tex,(float)threadIdx.x,(float)threadIdx.y,(float)threadIdx.z);//by using this the error occurs
        printf("thread: %d,%d,%d, value: %f\n", threadIdx.x, threadIdx.y, threadIdx.z, test);
}

void CreateTexture(int num, cudaTextureObject_t *texNoise, cudaArray **d_cuArr, float **d_NoiseTest)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        cudaSetDevice(i);
        cudaMalloc((void **)&d_NoiseTest[i], cubeSizeNoiseTest*sizeof(float));//Allocation of device Array
        //curand Random Generator (needs compiler link -lcurand)
        curandGenerator_t gen;
        curandCreateGenerator(&gen,CURAND_RNG_PSEUDO_DEFAULT);
        curandSetPseudoRandomGeneratorSeed(gen,1235ULL+i);
        curandGenerateUniform(gen, d_NoiseTest[i], cubeSizeNoiseTest);//writing data to d_NoiseTest
        curandDestroyGenerator(gen);

        //cudaArray Descriptor
        cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<float>();
        //cuda Array
        checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc3DArray(&d_cuArr[i], &channelDesc, make_cudaExtent(SizeNoiseTest*sizeof(float),SizeNoiseTest,SizeNoiseTest), 0));
        cudaMemcpy3DParms copyParams = {0};


        //Array creation
        copyParams.srcPtr   = make_cudaPitchedPtr(d_NoiseTest[i], SizeNoiseTest*sizeof(float), SizeNoiseTest, SizeNoiseTest);
        copyParams.dstArray = d_cuArr[i];
        copyParams.extent   = make_cudaExtent(SizeNoiseTest,SizeNoiseTest,SizeNoiseTest);
        copyParams.kind     = cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice;
        checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy3D(&copyParams));
        //Array creation End

        cudaResourceDesc    texRes;
        memset(&texRes, 0, sizeof(cudaResourceDesc));
        texRes.resType = cudaResourceTypeArray;
        texRes.res.array.array  = d_cuArr[i];
        cudaTextureDesc     texDescr;
        memset(&texDescr, 0, sizeof(cudaTextureDesc));
        texDescr.normalizedCoords = false;
        texDescr.filterMode = cudaFilterModeLinear;
        texDescr.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeClamp;   // clamp
        texDescr.addressMode[1] = cudaAddressModeClamp;
        texDescr.addressMode[2] = cudaAddressModeClamp;
        texDescr.readMode = cudaReadModeElementType;
        checkCudaErrors(cudaCreateTextureObject(&texNoise[i], &texRes, &texDescr, NULL));}
}
void FreeTexture(int num, cudaTextureObject_t *texNoise, cudaArray **d_cuArr, float **d_NoiseTest)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
     cudaFree(d_NoiseTest[i]);
     cudaDestroyTextureObject(texNoise[i]);
     cudaFreeArray(d_cuArr[i]);}
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int num_dev = 1;
        if (argc > 1) num_dev = atoi(argv[1]);
        cudaTextureObject_t *texNoise = new cudaTextureObject_t[num_dev];
        cudaArray **d_cuArr = new cudaArray*[num_dev];
        float **d_NoiseTest = new float*[num_dev];
        CreateTexture(num_dev, texNoise, d_cuArr, d_NoiseTest);
        for (int i = 0; i < num_dev; i++){
          cudaSetDevice(i);
          AccesTexture<<<1,dim3(2,2,2)>>>(texNoise[i]);}
        checkCudaErrors(cudaPeekAtLastError());
        for (int i = 0; i < num_dev; i++){
          cudaSetDevice(i);
          checkCudaErrors(cudaDeviceSynchronize());}
        FreeTexture(num_dev, texNoise, d_cuArr, d_NoiseTest);
        delete[] d_cuArr;
        delete[] d_NoiseTest;
        delete[] texNoise;
        return 0;
}
$ nvcc -I/usr/local/cuda/samples/common/inc -lcurand -o t342 t342.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t342
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
thread: 0,0,0, value: 0.310691
thread: 1,0,0, value: 0.627906
thread: 0,1,0, value: 0.638900
thread: 1,1,0, value: 0.665186
thread: 0,0,1, value: 0.167465
thread: 1,0,1, value: 0.565227
thread: 0,1,1, value: 0.397606
thread: 1,1,1, value: 0.503013
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$ cuda-memcheck ./t342 2
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
thread: 0,0,0, value: 0.310691
thread: 1,0,0, value: 0.627906
thread: 0,1,0, value: 0.638900
thread: 1,1,0, value: 0.665186
thread: 0,0,1, value: 0.167465
thread: 1,0,1, value: 0.565227
thread: 0,1,1, value: 0.397606
thread: 1,1,1, value: 0.503013
thread: 0,0,0, value: 0.809163
thread: 1,0,0, value: 0.795669
thread: 0,1,0, value: 0.808565
thread: 1,1,0, value: 0.847564
thread: 0,0,1, value: 0.853998
thread: 1,0,1, value: 0.688446
thread: 0,1,1, value: 0.733255
thread: 1,1,1, value: 0.649379
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$ cuda-memcheck ./t342 3
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
thread: 0,0,0, value: 0.310691
thread: 1,0,0, value: 0.627906
thread: 0,1,0, value: 0.638900
thread: 1,1,0, value: 0.665186
thread: 0,0,1, value: 0.167465
thread: 1,0,1, value: 0.565227
thread: 0,1,1, value: 0.397606
thread: 1,1,1, value: 0.503013
thread: 0,0,0, value: 0.809163
thread: 1,0,0, value: 0.795669
thread: 0,1,0, value: 0.808565
thread: 1,1,0, value: 0.847564
thread: 0,0,1, value: 0.853998
thread: 1,0,1, value: 0.688446
thread: 0,1,1, value: 0.733255
thread: 1,1,1, value: 0.649379
thread: 0,0,0, value: 0.040824
thread: 1,0,0, value: 0.087417
thread: 0,1,0, value: 0.301392
thread: 1,1,0, value: 0.298669
thread: 0,0,1, value: 0.161962
thread: 1,0,1, value: 0.316443
thread: 0,1,1, value: 0.452077
thread: 1,1,1, value: 0.477722
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

This code was run on a system that has (at least) 3 GPUs.  I've also updated the above example so it demonstrates how to create an array of pointers to `cudaArray` type, and also demonstrating how one could avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the way to go. Just the single question: Using this system, you need to know the number of GPUs on the system in compile time? You have 4 `NUM_TEX` but only use 3 devices in your test. Is this because you do not have 4 devices installed and therefore the 4th creation of the texture does not happen? I am just not sure if I am missing something there

Comment: Nothing about this should be compile-time dependent.  I've added a variant to the answer demonstrating this.

Comment: Ah, I see now, I got a bit confused with that global definition. Thanks, fantastic answer as usual!

Comment: Hi Robert, just a follow up question which is somehow related to my original one. In here, you do not store each instance of the `d_cuArr`, as you clearly mentioned, but for safe coding, I'd need to store those and properly deallocate them when not needed. This arises again the question in the title, how do I create an array of those in order to properly free them later? I know how to do it for `d_NoiseTest`, but not for `d_cuArr` due to its `cudaArray` type.

Comment: What is it about the `cudaArray` type that prevents you from creating an array of them?  What would it be about the `cudaArray` type that prevents you from creating an array of pointers to them?  This is just a C/C++ programming question now.  The methodology could be similar to what I did with `texNoise`, which is a pointer to an array of `cudaTextureObject_t` type.  Anyway, I've updated the last example in my answer.

Comment: Apologies this was on me. I was doing something stupid and getting Compile errors that I though it was because I could not do this. In fact it was not. Apologies for the extra time it took.

Comment: No problem.  To some degree these things force me to write better answers.  Now its less likely in the future that someone will say "did you know this code you posted here has a memory leak..."  And arguably the `d_NoiseTest` array could be encapsulated in the create function.  It does not really need to be passed back and forth to `main`, unless you wanted that data for some other use.

Comment: In fact this last version suits my case a bit better, as instead of a device array I am passing a host array and copying to the `d_cuArr` from that, and perhaps that is a more realistic case than a random array input. I think the answer is really good as it is, thanks for the teaching, as usual!